# More confused than ever with units of work vs. none and dodging micro-management of Transactions in Repository!

Tags: c#, nhibernate, repository-pattern

I had come to the conclusion that there was no reason to use a UnitOfWork on top of a NHibernate session and was asking in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869896/need-help-understanding-nhibernate-transactions-and-how-not-to-duplicate-code-if) on the best way not to have to explicitly create a transaction for every database persistence action.

Only to be redirected back to the idea of a Unit of Work.  Well, further investigation has lead me back to where I was originally not to implement a separate Unit of Work pattern on top of NHibernate (one [example](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/07/30/the-false-myth-of-encapsulating-data-access-in-the-dal.aspx), amongst others).

My problem is how do you not use a Unit of Work, AND not micro-manage a transactions in a repository and keep it separate?

Comment: I thought the lifestyle management of nHibernate took care of this for you. What seems to be the issue with using per-request?

Comment: I have no problem with per-request, its the separation of my repository from a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still separate the repository from a transaction. The main thing you'll have to manage is the lifecycle of your session.

In your transaction manager you can write something like

```
public class TransactionManager
{
    private ISession session;

    public TransactionManager(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void BeginTransaction()
    {
         session.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void CommitTransaction()
    {
        session.Transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Then in your repository you would just inject the session

```
public class Repository
{
    private ISession session;

    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public T Get<T>(int id)
    {
        return session.Get<T>(id);
    }
}
```

If you're using the same session in the transaction manager as the repository. Your repository will operate with an explicit transaction.

Comment: I was doing the same thing with a Unit of Work which is more or less what I think you laid out - what I can't seem to wrap my head around is if you are not passing an instance of the "TransactionManager" to the repository how would you ever call BeginTransaction() or CommitTransaction()?

Comment: This isn't a unit of work implementation. It can be used in a unit of work implementation, however. If you don't want the repository to micro manage the transaction, the code that uses the repository will have to manage the transaction.

Comment: Ok.  But still, how are you going to call either one of those methods if your not passing the "TransactionManager" object?

Comment: Passing it to what? Presumably the code that uses the repository will have an instance of the transaction manager. Since, in my opinion that's a huge pain and breaks patterns such as inversion of control, I would just use a unit of work pattern to manage my transactions.